# My code is not working. Write a C program to find GCD and LCM of ‘n’ numbers, with n being the input from user

Tags: c, lcm

I thought of declaring the variables first, and then finding the gcd and lcm. But when I tried to run, my code is not working. And the VS code is not even showing the errors. I am posting my code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= a && j <= b; ++j)
    {
         if (a % j == 0 && b % j==0)
            return j;
    }
}
int main ()
{
    int i, n, pro=1, g, t, lcm;
    int num[n];
    printf ("Enter the no. of numbers: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i <= n-1; i++)
    {
        printf ("Enter the number: ");
        scanf ("%d", &num[i]);
    }

    g = gcd (num[0], num[1]);

    for (t=2; t <= n; t++)
        g = gcd(num[t], g);

    for (i=0; i <= n-1; i++)
        pro = pro*num[i];

    lcm = pro/g;
    printf ("GCD is %d\n", g);
    printf ("LCM is %d", lcm);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please be **explicit** about what you mean by "not working".

Comment: I see one thing: you must define `int num[n];` *after* you know its length `n`. Unlike a spreadsheet, C does not adjust itself retrospecdtively,

Comment: Please describe what exactly is not working. Also add your input, output and expected output.

Comment: Aside: there are far better algorithms for calculating gcd (such as the Euclidean algorithm). The brute force method will be horribly inefficent for large values.

Comment: The *modulus* of something and `1` will always be `0`. Dividing by `1` wil never leave a remainder. `1` is not a prime number.

Comment: The solution here always returns `1` and there is a compiler warning: not all control paths return a value. Also, `for (t=2; t <= n; t++)` will break the bounds of the array. In the following loop, the `i <= n-1;` is not idiomatic, can be faulty, and should be `i < n;`

Comment: You're going to find your LCM calculation only works for two numbers. It requires a more elegant operation than you're doing to chain three or more numbers into a final LCM result. Hint: LCM(a,b) = (a\*b)/GCD(a,b) (which you seem to already know), and LCM(a,b,c) = LCM(LCM(a,b),c) (which you seem *not* to know).

Comment: Well, I tried putting the inputs, but the gcd is coming 1. The answers aren't correct

Comment: And the question needs the user to enter the input. So, the length of the array can't be specified

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried doing it again. The problem with my code was that the `return j` was in the loop, and thus, it was returning the value of j instead of giving the value of g.

The corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    int g;
    for (int j = 2; j <= a && j <= b; ++j)
    {
        if (a % j == 0 && b % j==0)
        g = j;
    }
    return g;
}
int main ()
{
    int i, n, pro=1, g, t, lcm;
    
    printf ("Enter the no. of numbers: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    int num[n];
    for (i = 0; i <= n-1; i++)
    {
        printf ("Enter the number: ");
        scanf ("%d", &num[i]);
    }

    g = gcd (num[0], num[1]);

    for (t=2; t <= n; t++)
        g = gcd(num[t], g);

    for (i=0; i <= n-1; i++)
        pro = pro*num[i];

    lcm = pro/g;
    printf ("GCD is %d\n", g);
    printf ("LCM is %d", lcm);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just fyi, this code [invokes *undefined behavior*](https://godbolt.org/z/vE7ssh176) by breaching `num` in the `t` loop, and does *not* find the correct LCM for 3+ arguments. Heed the comments above. In the posted example the input of 3 10 20 60 should result in a LCM of 60. You're returning 1200. [Consider this](https://godbolt.org/z/zxqvTEE9W).

Comment: The most idiomatic pattern for a loop condition to iterate over an array uses `< length` as a condition. If you get into the habit of using that instead of `<= length - 1`, you may find that (1) you type less code; (2) you have an easier time reading others' code; (3) you are less likely to step past the end of an array. If you did make a mistake by mixing approaches (say, `< length - 1`), the consequence would be that you look at too few elements, rather than introducing a more dangerous memory-related bug.